# How to organize classes and Lists for Java text adventure

Tags: java, class, oop, arraylist

I am creating a Java text adventure and am trying to make it as object-oriented as possible. I'm debating how to handle the Rooms and the available items in that room.  Currently I have the room class set up like this:

```
 String name;
 String description;
 List<Item> avaliableItems;
 List<Item> inspectableItems;

Room(String name, String description, List<Item> avaliableItems, List<Item> inspectableItems,) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.avaliableItems = avaliableItems;
    this.inspectableItems = inspectableItems;
}
```

I have a Game class which I planned on initializing the Rooms and I also have an Input class which checks the user input and performs actions.  My problem is I don't know what to do with the Item lists.  I don't want to have to create a new Room and multiple new Lists for each room. I feel like this would get messy very quickly. Is there a way to get this same idea across in a cleaner way? Each room having its own class would be overboard I think. Thanks.

Comment: How do you determine what Items are available in what rooms?

Comment: Maybe you need consider some kind of configuration file or database

Comment: @ToddSewell Whatever I want the player to be able to pick up in that room.

Comment: @conyare And how do you want to code that information into the game? Configuration files? A database?

Comment: @ToddSewell I've never use those either of those methods before so I'm not familiar with them, but I might try to figure how to use a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day level creation is going to involve a bunch of hardcoded info. That can be messy if it is done wrong. One approach that has worked well for me is to serialize the rooms with their initial items into a text file, and then make one class which handles initializing all rooms based on the text file. That way you don't have lines upon lines of hardcoded item data in your code, and all of the level setup info is in one place.